# Regular expression for matching string?

Tags: javascript, regex

Here is my code:

```
var str="<table><tr><td>abraham</td></tr></table>";
```

How to get **abraham**  by matching `td` ?

I tried but failed, I don't want to match `table` or `tr`, I want to only match `td`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var str="<table><tr><td>anilkumar</td>";
var patt1=/<td>(\w+)<\/td>/;
document.write(str.match(patt1));
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

It ruturns **null**.

Comment: Your demo string, `"<table><tr><td>anilkumar<\td>"` has `"<\td>"` instead of `"</td>"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
var str="<table><tr><td>abraham</td></tr></table>";
var result = str.match(/<td>(\w+)<\/td>/); //"abraham"
document.write(result[1]);
```

**Edit:** If you have special characters between the `td`s (like whitespace) you can use:

```
var str="<table><tr><td>abraham asd</td></tr></table>";
var result = str.match(/<td>(.*?)<\/td>/); //"abraham asd"
document.write(result[1]);
```

[**Live demo.**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgechev/5bjkP/)

Comment: Yes, now it works. If you have special characters (like white space) you should use different regex (for example `.*?`).

Comment: `.*?` will not work with newlines. If that is a problem, you can use something like `/<td>([\s\S]*?)<\/td>/i`, because JavaScript doesn't have the `/s` flag (singleline, or dot-match-all).

Answer (score 1):

This should suit your needs:

```
<td>(.*?)</td>
```

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/hUpQm/).

Answer (score 1):

basically it is non-whitespace between > and <. Try, if

> >\s?(\w+)\s?<

fulfills your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Use this Expression : `^<\s*(td|TD)\s*(\w|\W)*\s*>(\w|\W)*</(td|TD)>$`

This match *** in html,so any other html mark with is just do a little change to this

Perfect Matches : `<td>hello kitty</td> OR <TD WIDTH='20></TD> OR <TD >&NBSP;</td>`

Comment: What do you think `\w|\W` means?

Comment: if you are using Asp.Net Regular Expression Validator then it works fine and if you are working in javascript then it may be some different i.e. <\s*(td|TD)\s*(\w|\W)*\s*>(\w|\W)*</(td|TD)> Don't use ^ in begging and $ in ending.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.createElement), [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/element.innerHTML), and [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/Node.textContent):

```
var dummy = document.createElement('div');
dummy.innerHTML = str;
var text = dummy.textContent;
```

Or, using a library like jQuery (which will work better cross browser):

```
var text = $(str).text();
```

Working example of both: http://jsbin.com/acuyoq

Comment: Much better than a regex.  Parsing html with hand crafted regexes is pure folly.  The hard work has been done for us. ++ for you.